# Use Local Font in Next.js

Tags: css, fonts, next.js, font-face

I'm struggling to get a local font to work on my Next.js website and can't seem to find much on it. I used @font-face in my globals.css style-sheet. (I referenced https://kirazhang.com/posts/nextjs-custom-fonts).

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Adobe Caslon Pro";
  src: url("/static/fonts/ACaslonPro-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
  font-style: medium;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

then in _app.js

```
import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

I also [added a _document.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) file to my pages folder

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <link
          rel="preload"
          href="/static/fonts/ACaslonPro-Regular.otf"
          as="font"
          crossOrigin=""
        />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

When everything is said and done it gives me Times in New Roman when I inspect the webpage.

Comment: Where have you used the font? Just adding it won't apply it. Also, is your `static` directory inside `public`?

Comment: Yes, my static is inside public. I have used the font in Photoshop for a temporary logo and now the "OpenType font file" files are simply stored in the fonts folder. Am I missing something?  Thank you.

Comment: You need to set some style like `font-family: 'Adobe Caslon Pro', serif;` on the element you need to apply font to. Put it like this `html, body { font-family: '.....' }` if you want to apply it to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the installation of your font is good, but you have to call a class/className or style with this font-family inside your component.

Exemple:

```
<div style={{fontFamily: "Adobe Caslon Pro"}} >
Exemple
</div>
```