# In NextJS 14 utilizing Chakra how to load local fonts?

Tags: next.js, fonts, chakra-ui, woff2

Unsure what the correct approach to using local fonts on a NextJS 14 app is (using app router not pages) but I've tried to use a custom-made local font in a Woff and Woff2 format. Per the Chakra UI option using [`@font-face`](https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/using-fonts#option-2-using-font-face) there is:

```js
import { Global } from '@emotion/react'

const Fonts = () => (
  <Global
    styles={`
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Heading Font Name';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url('./fonts/custom.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./fonts/custom.woff') format('woff');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
      }
      `}
  />
)

export default Fonts
```

and per research on this subject, I found "[How to use self-hosted fonts face using NextJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909298/how-to-use-self-hosted-fonts-face-using-nextjs)" which I implemented the `Head` solution of:

```js
const RootLayout = ({children}: RootLayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <link
          rel="preload"
          href="/fonts/custom-font.woff2"
          as="font"
          type="font/woff2"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

but I get the warning:

> Warning: You're using `next/head` inside the `app` directory, please migrate to the Metadata API. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-3-migrating-nexthead for more details.

there is nothing mentioned in the directed warning link regarding the correct approach to load local fonts with the Metadata API without Tailwind ([Local Fonts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#local-fonts)). Research on the topic mentioned solutions for TailWind but I have an entire design system developed in Chakra.

- [Font Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts)
- [How to add custom local fonts to a Nextjs 13 Tailwind project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607996/how-to-add-custom-local-fonts-to-a-nextjs-13-tailwind-project)
- [How to use self-hosted fonts face using NextJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909298/how-to-use-self-hosted-fonts-face-using-nextjs)
- [Local font not loading in NextJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757096/local-font-not-loading-in-nextjs)
- [Use Local Font in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149544/use-local-font-in-next-js)

With NextJS 14 and Chakra, what is the correct way to load a local Woff2 font?